# .pop() / slice.() on arrays not working. Need count working - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Really struggling with this one!

I'm building a donation form in ReactJS.  The form sits in another component, but works.  I can do the following:

1. Submit the donation number/amount.
2. Collect this via handleChange, which then sets this to the state "donated".
3. I can work out the sum of total donations.
4. How much money is needed to complete £200 worth of transactions.
5. And add some divs to a progress bar, each time a donation is made.  To make it look like the bar is filling up.

What has stopped working though, is my count of how many donations have been made.  All I'm doing is calling the length of the donated array, to represent how many donations are in the array:

```
   <div className="columns">
    <div className="column">
      <p>Only 3 days left to fund this project.</p>
      <p>Join the <strong>**{donated.length}**</strong> other donors who have already supported this project. Every dollar helps.</p>
      {/* <div>
        <ul>
          {donated.map((donated, i) => <li key={i}>{donated}</li>)}
        </ul>
      </div> */}
    </div>
  </div>
```

However, as I'm applying .pop() on my array in app.js, all my arrays are reduced to the last value in the array.  Therefore, my .length doesn't work.

I've tried to duplicate the array with .slice(0) on this.state.donated, but I couldn't get this to work. I basically ran into the same problem.  Or it messaged up my donation $.  Doubling numbers and messing up my sum..

I need .pop(-1), so my progress bar can fill up, depending on how much was submitted.  Please help?  Seems missy, I've moved code around.  And one works, or the other depending, on where I shift my code.

Happy for a basically DOM manipulation function too!  All I wanna to is count how many clicked submit/made a donation. Spent 5 hours on this!

Thank you.
Reena

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import ProgressBar from './components/ProgressBar';
import Form from './components/Form';

class App extends React.Component {

constructor() {
  super();

 this.state = {
  number: '',
  donated: [],
  sum: [],
  total: 0,
  remaining: 200,
  count: 0
};

this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
// we need to bind otherwise this is undefined
}

//HANDLE FUNCTIONS
  handleChange(e) {
this.setState({ number: e.target.value }, () => console.log('NUMBER', this.state.number));
}

 handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.setState({donated: this.state.donated.concat(this.state.number).map(Number)}, () => console.log('DONATED', this.state.donated));


 this.setState({sum: this.state.donated.concat(this.state.number).map(Number)}, () => {
  console.log('SUM', this.state.sum);

  // FUNCTION TO CALCULATE TOTAL DONATIONS
  const numbers = this.state.sum;
  function add(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  }

  // TOTAL VALUE OF NUMBERS IN THE ARRAY
  const calc = numbers.reduce(add, 0);
  console.log('CALC', calc);
  this.setState({total: calc});

  // CALCULATION FOR MONIES REMAINING
  this.setState({remaining: this.state.remaining - calc}, () => console.log('REMAINING', this.state.remaining));


  // LOOP TO PRINT OUT PROGRESS BAR ENTRIES
  for (var i = 0; i < this.state.donated.length; i++) {
    if (i < 200) {
      // div +1;
      const div = document.createElement('div');
      div.style.background = 'red';
      div.style.width = this.state.donated.pop() * 2 + 'px';
      div.style.height = '50px';
      div.style.float = 'left';
      document.querySelector('.bar').appendChild(div);
    }
  }

  document.forms['id_form'].reset();
});
}

render() {

return (
  <main>
    <section className="section">
      <h1 className="is-size-2">DONATE FOR A GOOD CAUSE</h1>
      <ProgressBar donated={this.state.donated} remaining={this.state.remaining}/>
      <Form donated={this.state.donated} handleChange={this.handleChange} handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit} />
    </section>
  </main>
  );
 }
}

ReactDOM.render(
<App />,
document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: I can see you are setting state.numbers and state.remaining but when you run the reduce function on numbers var which is in fact state.sum isn't the state.sum just empty, since you set only the state.numbers in the handleChange function?

Comment: No sum isn't empty, it's basically a duplicate of donated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add another counter and increment it for each donation. 
Use this counter to get the number of donations instead of using the array length.

Comment: Here's what, I'm trying  - I'd like to explore this option, if anyone can help me out with the correct code...
      const counter = this.state.count + 1;
      document.querySelector('.tally').innerHTML = counter;

Comment: Everytime a new donation is done you have to increment the counter like this.state.counter++  As counter has to be changed it cannot be const.

Comment: Just a tip, you shouldn't modify your state directly. You probably want to do this: `this.setState({ counter: this.state.counter + 1 })`.